# Monad Parser - Couldn't match expected type ‘[(b, String)]’ with actual type ‘Parser b’

Tags: parsing, haskell, types, functional-programming, monads

I'm studying Haskell using "Programming in Haskell" of G.Hutton. I'm following ch.13 of Monadic Parser.
First, I define a type Parser:

```
newtype Parser a = P (String -> [(a, String)])
```

Then, a parse function

```
parse:: Parser a -> String -> [(a, String)]
```

I make the Parser a Monad

```
instance Monad Parser where
--return :: a -> Parser a
 return v =  P(\inp -> [(v, inp)])

--(>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
 p >>=  g = P (\inp -> case parse p inp of
  [] -> []
  [(v, out)] -> parse (g v) out)
```

My problem is on the last line of Monad instance
Why this

```
[(v, out)] -> parse (g v) out)
```

and not this

```
[(v, out)] -> (g v))
```

`>>=` return a Parser b, not a `[(b, String)]`.Infact `g v`, is a Parser.

I know I'm wrong, but I don't understand why.

Comment: You wrap it in a `P` constructor, hence it should be of type `String -> [(a,String)]`. That being said, the parser is not yet complete, since it is possible that the list contains more than one element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`>>=` return a Parser b, not a [(b, String)].Infact `g v`, is a `Parser`.

That is correct, but we are constructing a `Parser` with the outer `P`. Indeed:

```
p >>=  g = P (\inp -> case parse p inp of
  [] -> []
  [(v, out)] -> parse (g v) out)
```

Notice the `P` here immediately after the `=`. The lambda expression `\inp -> …` thus has to have as type `String -> [(b, String)]`, not `Parser`. We evaluate the parser with `parse`, since that acts as a "getter" to get the function out of the `g v`.

Your implementation of `>>=` is however not complete. Indeed, this is a backtracking parser, and it is possible that the list contains no elements (no options), one element, or *multiple* elements. We thus should perform a mapping like:

```
p >>= g = P (
    \inp -> concatMap (\(v, out) -> parse (g v) out) (parse p inp)
  )
```

or we can make use of the bind operator `>>=` defined for lists:

```
p >>= g = P (
    \inp -> parse p inp >>= \(v, out) -> parse (g v) out
  )
```